# Jesting on Purim in commemoration of Achashverosh?

Tags: purim

In [Siman 307:16, the Mishna Berura](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.307.16?lang=he&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.307.59&lang2=he) discusses the problems with frivolity and mentions that **even on Purim, *merriment* is only permitted when done *in commemoration of Achashverosh***!

What does he mean by that? What part of Achashverosh - or his behavior - are we remembering by being merry?

> וגם בפורים אין מותר רק השחוק שעושים **זכר לאחשורוש**

BTW:  Achashverosh does not appear even once in Hilchot Purim in the Shulchan Aruch!

---

The full sources:

[Shulchan Aruch 307:16](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.307.16?lang=he&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.307.59&lang2=he):

> מליצות ומשלים של שיחת חולין ודברי חשק כגון ספר עמנואל וכן ספרי מלחמות אסור לקרות בהם בשבת ואף בחול אסור **משום מושב לצים** ועובר משום אל תפנו אל האלילים לא תפנו אל מדעתכם ובדברי חשק איכא תו משום מגרה יצר הרע ומי שחיברן ומי שהעתיקן ואין צריך לומר המדפיסן מחטיאים את הרבים: הגה ונראה לדקדק הא דאסור לקרות בשיחות חולין וספורי מלחמות היינו דוקא אם כתובים בלשון לע"ז אבל בלשון הקודש שרי וכן נ"ל מלשון שכתבו התוס' פרק כל כתבי וכן נהגו להקל בזה:‏

[Mishna Berura (59)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.307.16?lang=he&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.307.59&lang2=he):

נט) **משום מושב לצים** - וכ"ש ההולך לטרטיאות וקרקסיאות [והם מיני שחוק כדאיתא בעבודת כוכבים דף י"ח] ושאר מיני תחבולות **וגם בפורים אין מותר רק השחוק שעושים זכר לאחשורוש** [מ"א] ובעו"ה כיום נעשה דבר זה כהפקר אצל איזה אנשים לילך לבית טרטיאות והכתוב צוח ואומר אל תשמח ישראל אל גיל וכו' וגם איכא בזה משום מגרי יצה"ר בנפשם ואחז"ל כל המתלוצץ נופל בגיהנם שנאמר וגו' ויסורין באין עליו שנאמר ועתה אל תתלוצצו פן יחזקו מוסריכם [ע"ש בגמרא עוד]:‏

[Magen Avraham (22) quoted by the Mishna Berura](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.307.16?lang=he&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.307.59&lang2=he):

> משום מושב לצים. וה"ה ההולך לטרטיאות וקרקסיאות והם מיני שחוק כדאיתא בע"א דף י"ח ומיני תחבולה **ולא ידענא מי התיר להם בפורים ואפשר שנמשך להם משחוק שעושים זכר לאחשורוש** ועבב"י בח"מ סימן קס"ג ס"ט:‏

The [Bet Yosef mentioned by the Magen Avraham](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Beit_Yosef%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.163.7.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) does not reference Achashveirosh

Comment: @JoelK - it would fit in with the Mechaber's mention of Sefer Emanual - which was a 14th-century satire (I discovered on Wikipedia); not nearly as ancient as the name would seem to suggest.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that Magen Avraham is referring to the evolution of the customary [Purim *spiel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_spiel) (Purim play) from a comedy depicting King Achashveirosh and the Purim story, to other dramatizations. To quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_spiel):

> By the 18th century in eastern Romania and some other parts of Eastern Europe, Purim plays (called Purimshpiln, Yiddish: פּורימשפּילן‎) had evolved into broad-ranging satires with music and dance, precursors to Yiddish theater, for which the story of Esther was little more than a pretext: indeed, by the mid-19th century, some were even based on other stories, such as Joseph sold by his brothers, Daniel, or the Binding of Isaac.

The original version of the *spiel*, telling the story of Megillat Esther, was known as the [Achashveirosh-*spiel*](https://www.thoughtco.com/the-purim-shpiel-throughout-history-2077040).

So it seems that Magen Avraham, and by extension Mishnah Berurah, were willing to permit a play of the Purim story on Purim, but not other forms of drama.

---

For an interesting first-hand account of the Achashveirosh-*spiel*, [Jacob Frank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Frank) writes in [The Collection of the Words of the Lord, §1036](https://archive.org/details/TheCollectionOfTheWordsOfTheLordJacobFrank/page/n285)*:

> When I was little, I myself would make as if to play the game which the Jews enjoyed which they called Ahasuerus. Having made up in a garment of paper and with mats, I myself would be Mordechai, Haman and his wife Zeresh.

<sub>*Hat-tip to [this post](http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=8603) on forum.otzar.org for leading me to this source.</sub>